# Shiny renderUI does not show different D3 Plots after Changing the Tab in TabsetPanel

Tags: javascript, r, d3.js, shiny, networkd3

### **What I want to do**

I am trying to build a shiny app, that shows different interactive HTML-plots using a tabset panel. They all should show up in the same call of `renderUI`. As shown below in my example, my plots are based on the `d3` framework (as in the packages `networkD3` and`processanimateR`).

### **The Problem**

Unfortunately, only the first plot that is generated is shown by `renderUI`. Once the tab is changed, the second plot does not show up. `processanimateR` gives me the error `Failed to render the graph. It is probably too large. Original error: TypeError: d3.create is not a function at PATokens.insertTokens (<anonymous>:185:25) at <anonymous>:52:33 at <anonymous>:105:9`. Of course, the plot is not too large to be shown (data-wise), as changing the tab-sequence generates it perfectly.
This behavior is independent of which plot shows first. In the example below, I marked the lines you can use to swap `tab01` and `tab02` to see what happens.

### **What I tried**

By coming up with the smallest example I could, I possibly ruled out a lot of sources for error.
Additionally, I have tried using multiple `uiOutput` (one per tab) without success. The problem persists. As this minimal example suggests, it might be a problem with `d3` running in the background. Maybe there's some graphical engine that doesn't close on tab-change or something else `js` related.

### **My question**

Is there a way to show multiple `d3` plots in a shiny app, making them all show up as intended?

Thank you in advance!

### **My example**

```
#XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
#XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
# Settings
#XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
#XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
# Packages
sapply(c("shiny","processanimateR","bupaR","networkD3"),require,character.only=T)

# data
x <- structure(list(
    activity = c(
        "action 1", "action 2", "action 3", 
        "action 5", "action 2", "action 3", "action 25", "action 26", 
        "action 2", "action 3", "action 1", "action 2", "action 3", "action 1", 
        "action 2", "action 3", "action 1", "action 2", "action 3", "action 5", 
        "action 2", "action 3", "action 25", "action 26", "action 2", 
        "action 3", "action 1", "action 2", "action 3", "action 1", "action 2", 
        "action 3"),
    id = c(494.18, 494.18, 494.18, 485.56, 485.56, 485.56, 
           413.99, 413.99, 413.99, 413.99, 439.49, 439.49, 439.49, 466.38, 
           466.38, 466.38, 494.18, 494.18, 494.18, 485.56, 485.56, 485.56, 
           413.99, 413.99, 413.99, 413.99, 439.49, 439.49, 439.49, 466.38, 
           466.38, 466.38), .order = 1:32,
    activity_instance_id_by_bupar = c(1L, 
                                      2L, 3L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 71L, 
                                      72L, 73L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 60L, 
                                      61L, 62L, 71L, 72L, 73L),
    lifecycle_id = c("start", "start", 
                     "start", "start", "start", "start", "start", "start", "start", 
                     "start", "start", "start", "start", "start", "start", "start", 
                     "complete", "complete", "complete", "complete", "complete", "complete", 
                     "complete", "complete", "complete", "complete", "complete", "complete", 
                     "complete", "complete", "complete", "complete"),
    timestamp = structure(c(1424304001, 
                            1377475201, 1516579201, 1384128001, 1375401601, 1397952001, 1328486401, 
                            1364688001, 1318032001, 1384905601, 1348099201, 1342483201, 1366416001, 
                            1361404801, 1358726401, 1384905601, 1425168001, 1378339201, 1517443201, 
                            1384992001, 1376265601, 1398816001, 1329350401, 1365552001, 1318896001, 
                            1385769601, 1348963201, 1343347201, 1367280001, 1362268801, 1359590401, 
                            1385769601),
                          tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
    trace = c("action 2,action 1,action 3", "action 2,action 1,action 3", 
              "action 2,action 1,action 3", "action 2,action 5,action 3", 
              "action 2,action 5,action 3", "action 2,action 5,action 3", 
              "action 2,action 25,action 26,action 3", "action 2,action 25,action 26,action 3", 
              "action 2,action 25,action 26,action 3", "action 2,action 25,action 26,action 3", 
              "action 2,action 1,action 3", "action 2,action 1,action 3", 
              "action 2,action 1,action 3", "action 2,action 1,action 3", 
              "action 2,action 1,action 3", "action 2,action 1,action 3", 
              "action 2,action 1,action 3", "action 2,action 1,action 3", 
              "action 2,action 1,action 3", "action 2,action 5,action 3", 
              "action 2,action 5,action 3", "action 2,action 5,action 3", 
              "action 2,action 25,action 26,action 3", "action 2,action 25,action 26,action 3", 
              "action 2,action 25,action 26,action 3", "action 2,action 25,action 26,action 3", 
              "action 2,action 1,action 3", "action 2,action 1,action 3", 
              "action 2,action 1,action 3", "action 2,action 1,action 3", 
              "action 2,action 1,action 3", "action 2,action 1,action 3"
    ),
    n = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
          3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3),
    absolute_frequency = c(3L, 
                           3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                           3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                           3L),
    relative_frequency = c(0.272727272727273, 0.272727272727273, 
                           0.272727272727273, 0.0909090909090909, 0.0909090909090909, 
                           0.0909090909090909, 0.0909090909090909, 0.0909090909090909, 
                           0.0909090909090909, 0.0909090909090909, 0.272727272727273, 
                           0.272727272727273, 0.272727272727273, 0.272727272727273, 
                           0.272727272727273, 0.272727272727273, 0.272727272727273, 
                           0.272727272727273, 0.272727272727273, 0.0909090909090909, 
                           0.0909090909090909, 0.0909090909090909, 0.0909090909090909, 
                           0.0909090909090909, 0.0909090909090909, 0.0909090909090909, 
                           0.272727272727273, 0.272727272727273, 0.272727272727273, 
                           0.272727272727273, 0.272727272727273, 0.272727272727273)),
    row.names = c(NA, 
                  -32L),
    class = c("eventlog", "log", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
    ),
    case_id = "id", activity_id = "activity", activity_instance_id = "activity_instance_id_by_bupar",
    lifecycle_id = "lifecycle_id",
    resource_id = "id",
    timestamp = "timestamp")
y <- jsonlite::fromJSON(paste0('https://cdn.rawgit.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/','master/JSONdata/energy.json'))

#XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
#XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
# Shiny-App UI ----
#XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
#XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
    title="shiny example",
    sidebarLayout(
        position="left",
        sidebarPanel(),
        mainPanel(
            tags$div(
                do.call(
                    tabsetPanel,
                    c(id='tabs',
                      lapply(1:2,function(y){
                          tabPanel(id=paste0("tab0",y),value=paste0("tab0",y),title=strong(paste0("This is tab0",y),align="left",style="black"),selected=1)
                      })
                    )
                ),
                uiOutput("out_ui")
            )
        )
    ),
    style=paste0("font-family: Arial;")
))

#XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
#XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
# Shiny-App Server ----
#XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
#XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
server <- function(input,output,session){
    output$out_ui <- renderUI({
        
        # X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X
        # >>>> Problem Segment <<<< ----
        # X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X
        # Try: Chance this to "tab01"
        if(input$tabs=="tab02"){
            
            # Process
            animate_process(
                x,
                processmap=process_map(
                    x,
                    type=frequency("absolute",color_scale="Paired",color_edges="Greys"),
                    rankdir="TB",render=F,fixed_edge_with=T,
                    layout=layout_pm(
                        edge_weight=F,
                        edge_cutoff=0)),
                mapping=token_aes(
                    size=token_scale(8),
                    color=token_scale(
                        range="black",
                        scale="ordinal"
                    ),
                    opacity=token_scale(100)
                ),
                duration=60,mode="absolute",timeline=T,jitter=10,initial_time=0,
                repeat_count=10,repeat_delay=2,width=1200,height=900,
                sizingPolicy=htmlwidgets::sizingPolicy(
                    browser.fill=T,viewer.fill=F,
                    knitr.figure=F,knitr.defaultWidth="100%",knitr.defaultHeight="1000")
            )
            
        # X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X
        # >>>> Problem Segment <<<< ----
        # X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X
        # Try: Chance this to "tab02"
        }else if(input$tabs=="tab01"){
            
            # Sankey
            sankeyNetwork(
                Links=y$links,Nodes=y$nodes,Source='source',
                Target='target',Value='value',NodeID='name',
                units='TWh',fontSize=12,nodeWidth=30
            )
        }
    })
}
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)

#XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
#XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 2):

I can tell you why it's not working. The `processAninmateR` uses D3 5.7. `networkD3` uses D3 4.5. I checked to make sure that my packages were up to date; no such luck. It doesn't look like there's a version of these packages where they match either.

Here's a workaround. This has you saving the Sankey, but you could save the process animation instead (with `saveWidget`). When you save this file, it needs to be in the directory of your shiny.R file or a subdirectory of that file. If you use the code shown here, it will automatically save it in the right place.

There were several odd things happening in your code, but I am going to take a wild guess and say that that is because you have probably tried a million and one ways to make this work.

You can replace the information you have for the `else if` call with the following:

```
# save to an object
sn <- sankeyNetwork(Links = y$links, Nodes = y$nodes, Source = 'source',
                    Target = 'target', Value = 'value', NodeID = 'name',
                    units = 'TWh', fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 30)
saveNetwork(sn, "sankey.html")               # save in local folder
addResourcePath("tmp", getwd())              # connect with file 
tags$iframe(src = "tmp/sankey.html", width = "100%",  # show plot in page
            frameBorder = "0", height = "500px")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Good to know that the version incompatibility is the cause of the problems. However, as the app will run on a server later, I am not sure if creating temp-files is the solution that I'm seeking. I will test it next week and come back to the answer. And please tell me about the odd things you discovered - I suppose they are more a product of this small example than my real project (but it will be good to know about them to rule them out in the app if possible).